# I have an editable SWF with Refferal protection, how would I remove that

Tags: flash, swf

Im using JPEXS to edit an SWF I obtained of MutilateADoll2 that is Site locked (referrer) to the kongregate website, is it possible to.... per say... Remove that referral lock and gain access to use the swf offline (via embed)

Comment: You realize you're asking game developers how to take and use the work of other game developers, without their permission and in a way they've apparently gone to some lengths to say they're not OK with you doing? While I want to assume you have the best of intentions here, I hope you can understand why we might be reluctant to show you how to counter our fellow game developers' express wishes this way, in a public forum where any unscrupulous actor could use the information for nefarious ends. ;)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about stealing a game

Comment: Sorry for giving the wrong impression, I extract games to use them FOR ME PERSONALLY to use offline. I DON'T want to ruin the developers work. I just wanted to know if there was a way to remove the site lock so I could convert it to exe, then be able to play it offline, I know I already have the steam version, (full version + exe) but I want to be able to embed it to my raspberry pi server so I can use it anywhere and download it without wifi (I got that all covered, I just dont know how to remove the Sitelock)

Comment: I heard the sitelock was like a `_as3_ not > _as3_ nop` thing but i couldnt find the as3 not thing in the main.as

Comment: @TaylorSpark If you have questions about personal use of games, then https://gaming.stackexchange.com would be the correct Stack Exchange. But I doubt that they will help you either.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about the development of games as defined in the help center.

Answer (score 2):

As described in the comments above, even given that your intentions are perfectly noble, this is a publicly visible site. If we told you how to defeat a game developer's protections on their game here, any bad actor could come along and use that information to rip off our fellow developers' hard work.

So, I hope you'll understand that many users of this site would find it unethical to post an answer about how to defeat this type of protection.

So, instead of "how can *I remove* this protection", I'd recommend we approach this question from the direction of **"how can *I obtain* a version of this game that works offline?"**

Here, the best approach we can offer you is to contact [the game's original developer](https://www.kongregate.com/accounts/0rava), eg. [via their Twitter account](https://twitter.com/dashrava), and ask if they would be willing to share a non-protected version with you / grant you a licence to use their work in the way that you describe.